# Use gradle dependency locking & version ranges in local library

Tags: java, gradle, build

I just started using dependency locking with version ranges (e.g. latest.release, 2.+, etc.) in one of my Java projects. To simplify, let’s say it has a structure like this:

```
:root:lib1
:root:project1
:root:project2
```

where lib1 is shared by the other 2 subprojects.

I started using dependency locking in :root:project1 and everything works as intended. :smiling_face_with_three_hearts:

Then I started using dependency locking with version ranges in `:root:lib1.` e.g. I would define a dependency like so: `implementation software.amazon.awssdk:sqs:latest.release` and then lock it to a version, say `1.0.0`. This works fine with the first project since I generate a separate lockfile for that project, which constrains the version of the library to whatever value is in that file.

However, in project2, I have not yet switched to dependency locking, and I see that it’s pulling in transitive dependencies as version `latest.release` instead of `1.0.0` (the value in the lockfile for the library), which resolves to different version day to day.

project2 declares a dependency on lib1 using the project annotation

```
    implementation project(':root:lib1')
```

Do I need to publish the lib1 jar and consume a specific version of it in order to get the locked transitive dependencies? Or is there a way to transitively bring the locked versions from lib1 instead of the `latest.release` value? Any help is much appreciated :slight_smile:

Currently using Gradle version 7.4.2

Comment: At the very bottom of the docs, there is [a note about limitations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_locking.html#locking_limitations).

I was originally assuming this only applied when suing remote source dependencies and not composite builds, but since they are very similar under the hood, I’m guessing this is a known limitation. Would be grateful if anyone is able to confirm.